# Adding sources for IntelliJ plugin via Gradle

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I've setup an IntelliJ plugin using Gradle. My `build.gradle` file contains:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.jetbrains.intellij' version '0.3.12'
}

//...

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}

intellij {
    version '2018.2.4'
    plugins 'git4idea'
}
```

Is there any way how I can include/download the sources of the Git4Idea plugin to the project so that they are available automatically?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. It'a bug. I filed it here on the [plugin's issue tracker](https://github.com/JetBrains/gradle-intellij-plugin/issues/337).